# Service Appointment on fsl mobile not show on some device

Tags: field-service-lightning

When I create Service Appointment cempleted, The Service Appointment can show on field service lightning app(fsl mobile), When I test on Iphone6s+ it's show in app, But when I test on IPhone7 and IphoneX it's not show in app (log in same user)

I tried re-login, purge cached Metadata, reinstall app on IPhone7 and IphoneX.It's not work.

Thanks advance
Kritsada

Comment: I recommend you file a case with support since all of those versions of iPhones are supported for FSL. This sounds like it could be a bug or possibly related to your service provider. Support should be able to help you troubleshoot the issue better than we will be able to here.

Comment: I opened this case support and waiting response from tem

Comment: I found the root of problem, This problem about Calendar of ios (Settings > General > Language&Region > Calendar) It's should be Gregorian.(in my case my device use Calendar Buddhist when I change to Gregorian, SA is showing)

Comment: Thanks for posting back in the comments to let us know. This might be helpful in the future to someone else should they run into the problem! Please post an answer your question and accept it so it will gain higher visibility in search results. I'll even make a point of upvoting it for you to give you some reputation. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the root of this problem is **Setting Calendar** in ios (Settings > General > Language&Region > Calendar), **It's should be Gregorian.**(in my case my device use Calendar Buddhist when I change to Gregorian, SA is showing)